# Acrobat Run profiles with variables(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, acrobat

a preflight created based on [acrobat](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/preflight-variables-acrobat-pro.html),How can I set a value to the preflight before running.

```js
var oProfile = Preflight.getProfileByName("myPreflight");
var oThermometer = app.thermometer;
var textSize = 10;
//oProfile.SetVariable("textSize",textSize); how to do?
var myPreflightResult = this.preflight(oProfile,false,oThermometer );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a timeout :

```js
oProfile.SetVariable("textSize",textSize)
var result = undefined
var self = this // Not necessary, but to avoid problems

setTimeout(function(){
   result = self.preflight(oProfile,false,oThermometer)
}, 100) //The 100 is in 100ms , you can change it
```

Comment: TypeError: oProfile.setVariable is not a function.The js is running not in a browser but a acrobat javascript debugger.